# Lock in Grails not working

Tags: grails, locking, grails-orm

I'm facing some issues while using the lock in Grails.

The situation is the following:

I have a User class, and then another Class UserProperty which has a belognsTo=User Property.

Now to avoid the user concurrently modifing this properties I want to lock the user, and after that modify/add/delete new properties.

But the lock seems not to be working, since in both cases the request goes trough. The pseudocode looks something like this:

```
User.lock(userId)
log.info "Starting modifiying properties"
addRemoveOrChangePropertiesToUser(userId)
log.info "Finsih modifing properties"
User.save(flush: true)
```

The behavior that I'm expecting is, that the first request goes through and logs everything. And till that (since user is locked) the second request waits and then does the changes to the properties.

Based on the log files, I see a completetly different behavior. Both requests are processed without any waiting time (almos simultationiusly).

Do you have any idea, what am I doing wrong? Did I missunderstand some of the Concepts related to the db locking? How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: MySQL, should this make any difference?

Comment: Why is `user` lower-case? Are you calling the `lock(int id)` method on an object, not a static class method?

Comment: No, sorry just misspelling.. will correct it right now

Comment: Nicolas, what mysql storage engine do you use for this table? InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Hi Splix, I didn't change it, so I assume it is the mysql default one. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into a similar problem where my function was in a controller. I thought that other threads should be blocked once hitting the .lock statement, but that wasn't happening. Wrapping the whole thing in a transaction fixed the problem for me.

So something like this:

```
User.withTransaction {
    User.lock(userId)
    log.info "Starting modifiying properties"
    addRemoveOrChangePropertiesToUser(userId)
    log.info "Finsih modifing properties"
    User.save()
}
```

In hindsight this makes sense I guess. I suspect the transaction is required to provide a clear demarcation (a unit of work) otherwise how does GORM/hibernate know when it can release the lock?

Controller methods have an open session but are not wrapped in a transaction. Service methods are wrapped in a transaction by default and I suspect we would not see this issue there.

Comment: This is good, but moving it to a transactional service method would be best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is how the lock works.  It's my understanding that it locks the entity from OTHERS updating the same instance when they obtain it from the hibernate session.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure you're implementing this correctly.  I think you need to obtain an instance - then lock it like...

```
def instance = Thing.get(1)
instance.lock()
```

And then try to modify the locked instance.

Comment: That's a pseudocode. And this answer code piece is an antipattern mentioned it Grails documentation. This way is suggested: `def instance = Thing.lock(1)`